# in redshift, how can I use window functions to assign a count to a previous row's date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, retention

the title would be too wordy if I actually tried to cram it all in there but here's what I need help with...

We are trying to calculate retention of users. Our users have assignment start dates and assignment end dates that may overlap. What I need to do is look at all candidate assignments and determine if they are retained (30 days or less between previous end and new start). The tricky part: I need to assign the retention credit to the previous assignment end date. Here's a preview of the data:

```
month | user_id | start_date | end_date | rank | days_btw_assignment
    1     5       1-1-16      1-31-16     1       NULL
    2     5       2-14-16     4-15-16     2       15  
    6     4       6-01-16    11-01-16     1       NULL
    8     4       8-01-16    11-01-16     2       -81
```

Therefore for user 5, I would need to give credit of retention to the month of jan-16' because their assignment end date ends 1-31-16. For User 4, where there assignments overlap, I would give credit of retention to nov-16' because their previous assignment end date ends 11-01-16.

I've restricted this example to use cases where they only have 2 assignments, though, there could be more. I just need a step in the right direction and I can probably handle all other use cases by myself.

Here's the sample code I'm currently using:

```
with placement_facts as (select date_trunc('month',assignment_start_date) as month, user_id, assignment_start_date, assignment_end_date, rank () over (partition by user_id order by assignment_start_date asc), extract( day from assignment_start_date - lag(assignment_end_date, 1) over (partition by user_id order by assignment_start_date asc)) as time_btw_placement
from activations as ca
join offers on ca.offer_id = offers.id
where assignment_start_date != assignment_end_date
order by 2,4 asc)
select placement_facts.month, count(distinct case when time_btw_placement <=30 then user_id else null end) as retained_raw 
from placement_facts
group by 1;
```

Appreciate the help and please lmk if I nee to clarify anything!

Comment: Please  share sample data and required output..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then I think you can achieve what you want by replacing your use of `LAG()` with `LEAD()`. It's basically the same function but it looks at a given number of rows *ahead*.